# Reusing Parameters Passed to Query to Generate Form

Tags: ms-access, parameters

I have a form in MS Access that uses a query to generate a form.  The query looks something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM PEOPLE
WHERE LAST_NAME LIKE [Enter Last Name] & "%";
```

This of course creates a pop-up to enter the last name to search.  I want to do an action on the parameter `[Enter Last Name]`, but I cannot figure out how to access this parameter.  In a report I just set the value of a textbox to `=[Enter Last Name]`.  Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: There is a lot to be said for using a small form, it allows you to control input, it can be hidden and reused, and you can reference it wherever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do would be to add the parameter as an output column, e.g.

```sql
PARAMETERS [Enter Last Name] Text ( 255 );
SELECT People.*, [Enter Last Name] AS theParameter
FROM People
WHERE (((People.LastName) Like [Enter Last Name] & "*"));
```

Then you could refer to the [theParameter] column in the result set.